How to set maximum consecutive days in OR-Tools CP-SAT?
I manage employees' working days. If an employee works for {consecutive_count} consecutive days, they are given {rest} days off.
ex)

OK [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,...]
FAIL [0,0, ** 1,1,1,1,0, ** 1,0,0,1,0,...]
FAIL [0,0, ** 1,1,1,1,1, ** 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,...]

I came up with the following code, but it doesn't work as expected.
What could be the problem?
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()
employees = ["daniel","karla","sergio"]
dates=["12/1","12/2","12/3",...,"12/31"]
assignments = {}
for e in range(len(employees)):
    for d in range(len(dates)):
        assignments[(e, d)] = model.NewBoolVar(f"employee_{e}_dates_{d}")

# HERE IS MY CONSTRAINT PROBLEM
consecutive_count=4
rest=2 
for e in range(len(employees)):
    for d in range(len(dates) - consecutive_count-rest*2 +1):  
        model.Add(sum(assignments[(e, d+i )] for i in range(consecutive_count+rest*2)) <= consecutive_count)

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)
schedule = []
if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    for e in range(len(employees)):
        for d in range(len(dates)):
            if solver.Value(assignments[(e, d)]) == 1:
                schedule.append([dates[t], employees[e]])


edited
NEW CODE ↓↓
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()
employees = ["daniel","karla","sergio"]
dates=["12/1","12/2","12/3",...,"12/31"]
assignments = {}
for e in range(len(employees)):
    for d in range(len(dates)):
        assignments[(e, d)] = model.NewBoolVar(f"employee_{e}_dates_{d}")

# HERE IS MY CONSTRAINT PROBLEM
consecutive_count=4
rest=2 
    for e in range(employees):
        for t in range(len(time_slots)):
            meeting_span=[assignments[(e, t+i)] for i in range(consecutive_count) if t+i<len(time_slots)]
            rest_before=[assignments[(e, t-i-1)].Not() for i in range(rest) if t-i-1>=0 ]
            rest_after=[assignments[(e, t+consecutive_count+i)].Not()   for i in range(rest) if t+consecutive_count+i<len(time_slots)]
            
            if meeting_span and (rest_before or rest_after):
                condition = model.NewBoolVar(f"condition_employee_{e}_slot_{t}")
                model.Add(sum(meeting_span) ==consecutive_count).OnlyEnforceIf(condition)
                model.AddBoolAnd(rest_after+rest_before).OnlyEnforceIf(condition)

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)
schedule = []
if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    for e in range(len(employees)):
        for d in range(len(dates)):
            if solver.Value(assignments[(e, d)]) == 1:
                schedule.append([dates[t], employees[e]])


You may want to double-check the range in your constraint as you defined rest=2 and also multiply with 2.
Your current constraint basically requires in the sequence of 6 that max 4 are 1. It does not consider the order of the sequence.
As you stated, you have 2 constraints:

max. 4x in a row = 1
If 4x in a row = 1 -> min. 2x in a row = 0

Edit: you may also want to have another look at the related examples given on the ortools website
Cheers!

see https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py

hi thanks for sharing the link!
now I put my new code but it still doesn't work as expected.
What do you think about it?

It seems this is not your real code. It’s reasonable to provide a minimal working sample. But neither versions of your code should work at all (regardless of your CP-SAT model). I did not downvote your question, but I reckon this is the reason someone did downvote, after seeing the first few lines. That being said, the example Laurent referred to might be a little overwhelming, if you just started out. So again, you may want to check the Ortools website. There are easier examples in the guide section to help to understand the underlying concept and principles. Good luck!
